# Skaffold wont deploy Kustomize resources

Tags: kustomize, skaffold

I'm using Skaffold to deploy an application and the version which I use is `v2.0.1`. The apiVersion is `skaffold/v3` and I'm using the below command to deploy it. The helm resources are deployed but not the Kustomize resources.

```
skaffold run -p profile-one
```

The Skaffold Config file looks like

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v3
kind: Config
metadata:
  name: nginx-app
manifests:
  helm:
    releases:
      - ...
        ...
deploy:
  helm: {}
portForward:
  - ...
    ...
profiles:
  - name: profile-one
    patches:
      ....
      ....
    manifests:
      kustomize:
        paths:
          - ./path/to/kustomize/files
    deploy:
      kubeContext: my-context
```

But it doesn't seems to deploy the actual k8s resources. Any idea?

Comment: Maybe you can try "skaffold render"